# Does Javascript methods auto-escape quotes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, quotes

I want to know if javascript methods auto-escape quotes, because this code work:

**Example #1**

```
<?php $foo ="hey a quote ' "; ?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $foo; ?>" id="foo" />
<script>
    bar = document.getElementById('foo').value;
    alert(bar+'there is a quote, will it work? ,');
</script>
```

It displays the alert fine, but this one:

**Example #2**

```
<?php $foo ="hey a quote ' "; ?>
<button onclick="alert('<?php echo $foo; ?>');">test</button>
```

...doesn't.
**Obviously**, it's because the quote isn't escaped with a `\`.

But then again, neither is it in the first example, so why is that so ?
Does javascript's method auto-escape quote when it picked stuff from DOM ?

Or is it just the `value()` method maybe ?

I've found nothing, so if you have even the beginning of an answer, I''ll be glad.

Comment: Escaping quotes is necessary in JavaScript *source code* in order to make the parser understand what is intended in a string literal.  Once the parser has made the string value, the escapes are gone. The browser, similarly, builds a string value by responding to keyboard activity. It has no need for an escape mechanism; whatever keys are pressed, those characters go into the string.

Comment: The first snippet ends up as `<input type="text" value="hey a quote ' " id="foo" />` the second however ends up as `<button onclick="alert('hey a quote ' ');">test</button>` which is a syntax error

Comment: Note for example that to properly escape quotes in HTML for an attribute value, you use a totally different convention than in JavaScript source code (`&#34;` and `&#39;`). That's because you're talking to the *HTML* parser, not the JavaScript parser.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise Javascript doesn't write HTML in the source code like PHP does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is processed on the server, producing HTML (including embedded javascript in this case). This happens before the HTML is sent to the browser to interpret, including any JS.

You will see if you inspect the generated HTML source, that your second example becomes:

```
<button onclick="alert('hey a quote ' ');">test</button>
```

which isn't valid JS syntax.

Your first version works basically because you do not have an extraneous single quote in the code your PHP string is inserted into. The insertion instead produces:

```
<input type="text" value="hey a quote ' " id="foo" />
```

which is perfectly fine. And that value is then passed on to the `alert` call in the JS.

Comment: But why does `alert(bar+'there is a quote, will it work ,');` work since there is single quotes in between ?
It should be read by the browser as `alert('hey a quote ' there is a quote, will it work ,');` thus, breaking it right ?

Comment: Apologies, I just edited and gave more detail because I realised my original statement was misleading. The key point is that, at the point you insert the PHP string into the HTML with `<?php echo $foo; ?>`, there are no single quotes around with which the echoed value of `$foo` interferes. The single quotes in your Javascript a little later are fine, the PHP output doesn't interfere with this.

Comment: Alright, I think I get it. Since PHP insert HTML in the DOM, it can break, but not in JS since it's part of the DOM itself, and it only read it in my example. Like, if it's not in the source code of the JS code, it will work just fine ! Thanks a lot for your explanation

Comment: Happy to help. Always remember that PHP is essentially a glorified HTML templating language - it runs on the server and produces HTML code (as well as doing an arbitrary amount of other stuff such as reading from/writing to files, or to a database, or whatever else). That HTML - possibly including CSS and Javascript - is received by the browser and interpreted as HTML always is, the browser doesn't know or care that the content was generated by PHP as opposed to some other language, or if it were a static file.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is really that in the first code example, the quote appears in a context where there are no wrapping single quotes, so there is no ambiguity. If you would have wrapped the HTML attribute values with single quotes (which is valid HTML also), you'd have a problem:

```
<?php $foo ="hey a quote ' "; ?>
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $foo; ?>' id='foo' />
```

In that case the single quote should have been escaped as an HTML entity: `&apos;`:

```
<?php $foo ="hey a quote &apos; "; ?>
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $foo; ?>' id='foo' />
```

Now in the second code example you provided, the single quote will appear in wrapped single quotes (for the string literal passed to `alert`). This is an issue, because the single quote will now *end* the string literal, and the characters following it will lead to a syntax error.

Here the quote appears in a JavaScript string literal (the `alert` code), not as in the HTML context of the first example. In JavaScript string literals, single quotes can be escaped with the backslash.

So in both cases (HTML or JavaScript) you could need a form of escaping. They are different.

Note that none of this is related to PHP.